# Multisite logged into one wp-admin, move to another sites wp-admin asked to login again

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, cookies, network-admin

I have a small networks of sites setup locally,

```
mymainsite.localhost
mymainsite-variation1.localhost
mymainsite-variation2.localhost
```

I am logged into `mymainsite.localhost/wp-admin` and navigate to `mymainsite-variation1.localhost` I am asked to login, my assumption would be that the cookie is shared across my network? Am I incorrect in my thinking?

Would that only work if my multisites were setup like,

```
mymainsite.localhost
variation1.mymainsite.localhost
variation2.mymainsite.localhost
```

Obviosuly on launch to prod it will be frustrating for my editors and admins if they need a session per site.

For reference the relevant part of my wp-config.php looks like this,

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );


define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mymainsite.localhost' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2 );
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
```

Any help and guidance on getting a single login working across my network would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cookies are per-domain, so no, they won't be shared.